# Java Transposition cipher for loop

Tags: java, python, encryption

I have been trying to recreate a python function to decrypt messages using a transposition cipher. although it keeps giving me incorrect outputs and making the messages longer. I think the error is to do with the array and the for loop but I'm not 100% sure.

My code

```
public String TranspositionDecryptText (String EncryptedText, int Key) {

    double NumColumnsD = Math.ceil(EncryptedText.length() / Key);
    int NumColumns = (int) NumColumnsD;
    int NumRows = Key;
    int NumShadedBoxes = (NumColumns * NumRows) - EncryptedText.length();

    String NormalArray[] = new String[NumColumns];

    int col = 0;
    int row = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < EncryptedText.length(); i++) {

        NormalArray[col] = NormalArray[col] + EncryptedText.charAt(i);
        col = col + 1;

        if ((col == NumColumns) || ((col == NumColumns - 1) && (row >= NumRows - NumShadedBoxes))) {

            col = 0;
            row = row + 1;

        }

    }

    String NormalString = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < NormalArray.length; i++) {

        NormalString = NormalString + NormalArray[i];

    }

    return NormalString;

}
```

Python version http://inventwithpython.com/hacking/chapter9.html

```
 def decryptMessage(key, message):
     # The transposition decrypt function will simulate the "columns" and
     # "rows" of the grid that the plaintext is written on by using a list
     # of strings. First, we need to calculate a few values.

     # The number of "columns" in our transposition grid:
     numOfColumns = math.ceil(len(message) / key)
     # The number of "rows" in our grid will need:
     numOfRows = key
     # The number of "shaded boxes" in the last "column" of the grid:
     numOfShadedBoxes = (numOfColumns * numOfRows) - len(message)

     # Each string in plaintext represents a column in the grid.
     plaintext = [''] * numOfColumns

     # The col and row variables point to where in the grid the next
     # character in the encrypted message will go.
     col = 0
     row = 0

     for symbol in message:
         plaintext[col] += symbol
         col += 1 # point to next column

         # If there are no more columns OR we're at a shaded box, go back to
         # the first column and the next row.
         if (col == numOfColumns) or (col == numOfColumns - 1 and row >= numOfRows - numOfShadedBoxes):
             col = 0
             row += 1

     return ''.join(plaintext)
```

Comment: Just figured out there is multiple errors, but i have fixed one of them. Each value of an element of NormalArray is null when it should be blank, to fix this i used a for loop setting the values before adding to them, `for (int i = 0; i < NumColumns; i++) {
            
            NormalArray[i] = "";
            
        }`

Answer (score 0):

I found that the text string given needed to be divisible by the key for the decryption to work. After finding this I added a loop to add spaces to the end of the text before being encrypted so the decryption program then has to trim the returned text before. The code now looks like this :

```
public class TranspositionCipher {

public String TranspositionEncryptText (String Text, int Key) {

    while (Text.length() % Key != 0) {

        Text = Text + " ";

    }

    ArrayList EncryptedText = new ArrayList<String>(Key); // Creates an array with as many elements as key

    String HoldText = "";

    for (int col = 0; col < Key; col++) {

        int pointer = col;
        while (pointer < Text.length()) {

            HoldText = HoldText + Text.charAt(pointer);
            pointer = pointer + Key;

        }

        EncryptedText.add(col, HoldText);
        HoldText = "";

    }

    String EncryptedString = ""; // String version of encrypted text
    Iterator iter = EncryptedText.iterator(); // Used to go through the array

    while (iter.hasNext()) { // While there are more elements in the array

        EncryptedString =  EncryptedString + iter.next(); // Add the element to the string

    }

    return EncryptedString; // Return the encrypted text as a string

}

public String TranspositionDecryptText (String EncryptedText, int Key) {

    double NumColumnsD = Math.ceil(EncryptedText.length() / Key);
    int NumColumns = (int) NumColumnsD;
    int NumRows = Key;
    int NumShadedBoxes = (NumColumns * NumRows) - EncryptedText.length();

    String NormalArray[] = new String[NumColumns];

    int col = 0;
    int row = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < NumColumns; i++) {

        NormalArray[i] = "";

    }

    for (int i = 0; i < EncryptedText.length(); i++) {

        NormalArray[col] = NormalArray[col] + EncryptedText.charAt(i);
        System.out.println(NormalArray[col]);
        col = col + 1;

        if ((col == NumColumns) || ((col == NumColumns - 1) && (row >= NumRows - NumShadedBoxes))) {

            col = 0;
            row = row + 1;

        }

    }

    String NormalString = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < NormalArray.length; i++) {

        NormalString = NormalString + NormalArray[i];

    }

    NormalString = NormalString.trim();

    return NormalString;

    }

}
```